# What data to collect to create useful insights?

Tags: data, bigdata

I am creating a **Social Media** app and I want to know what type of data shall I collect to create useful insights for *Business* accounts or *Content Creators*? For example if I want to create an insight related to user engagement to a post, what data would be required for accurate insights? Not only user engagement insight but also other insights such as followers lost/gained, user interaction, etc. I also want to my app to be **privacy** concerned so **no personal data**.

Answer (score 0):

Well for engagement you would want to look at likes and comments, as well as the type of comments (ex. if people tag their friends in the comments).

Depending on the social media platform the business accounts may also have access to views, i.e. how many people actually see the post or visit the profile, in which case you can then look at the proportion of visitors/viewers who like, comment or share the content.

In terms of followers lost/gained you could track the followers lost/gained over time and correlate this to certain posts. Ideally you should add some categorical labels to the posts that indicate what kind of post it is, that way you can correlate the type of post to how many followers are lost or gained. Then if the business or content creator sees that a certain type of post makes them lose followers they avoid it, and if it makes them gain followers they can make more similar posts.